# Can Goodness-of-fit increase while noise also increases?

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, statistics, signal-synthesis, linear-prediction

[I saw a tweet with a good slide.](https://twitter.com/wesbonifay/status/1407005111759540225)  It has a Goodness-of-fit curve that goes up with Model Complexity.  There is a Generalizability curve.  Noise is cited as the difference between the GOF and Generalizability. [image]

Is that how most people are used to thinking about "noise"?

Comment: Here, I think they're using "noise" to mean that the model is saying something more and more wrong. It's the error in the forecast that the model gives you, rather than input noise (which is what I usually think of as noise).

Answer (score 2):

The figure means to illustrate a consequence of overfitting: if we fit train data too well, *we'll fit noise too*, and thus generalize poorer.

"Noise > regularity" can be thought of as low SNR (signal to noise ratio). But here comes a flaw: *there need not be noise* for overfitting to occur. We can imagine a sine-fitting algorithm where we fed a million samples of 5Hz, then tried predicting on 6Hz: it'll fail miserably, but  there's no noise.

Regardless, "noise" here is used to explain something rather than being a definition. It's not how we conceptualize noise.

The diagram is simplifying in yet another regard: greater complexity won't necessarily harm generalization. This is the [double descent](https://openai.com/blog/deep-double-descent/) phenomenon.

[image]

Comment: I guess your 5 Hz example with a 6 Hz model depends on how noise is being defined.  Which is kind of vague in my question.

Comment: @bliswell The 5Hz and 6Hz are pure sines without any distortion. It'd be strange to define either of them as "noise", but "noise" is general enough that they may qualify under some lens, yes. The diagram can also mean that if noise dominates the signal, we're likelier to fit the noise than anything useful.